# Redirect when click double click at single button

Tags: javascript

I try to find Q&A related to my question. But I couldn't find. I have created a code where if user click double or multi click at single link then he will redirect to error page.

**My Code is**

```
<script>
    var doubleClick = false;
    function myWillPageRedirect() {
        if(!doubleClick) {
            doubleClick = true;
            window.open("errorPage.html");
        }
    }
</script>
```

**But this is not working. Why?**
I want to create a secure page generally we can see in some bank or financial website.
I want to create `'if user click window back button then he will redirect to error page.'` **OR** if if click refresh <kbd>button</kbd> then same action will perform and redirect to `error page.` ..

> If this all code can make in Linux server backend code. It would be great. 
>   Please help. I am not saying to some create code for me , I am asking for help to some correct my code above or bit extra help to make them secure.

Thank you .

Comment: You can nest `click` events, write one `click` event into another and if the **second** `click` event is fired, redirect to another page. You can also set `timeout` event for that click event so that it works only like the actual double and **not** like two separate `clicks`

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<a href="#" ondblclick="myWillPageRedirect()">Double-click me</a>
```

JS:

```
if(performance.navigation){ //Check if the page was refreshed
    if( performance.navigation.type === performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD ){ 
        myWillPageRedirect();
    }
}

function myWillPageRedirect() { 
    window.open("errorPage.html");
}

window.onhashchange = function() { //Check if the url has changed (in case of pressing back button)
 myWillPageRedirect();
}
```

More infos about [Performance.navigation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/navigation)

Comment: PLease convert this code in to server side language. I means nobody can see in page source.